# Adding class to element after render

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I have a component with a dynamically defined svg image that I'm trying to animate.

```
<div class="special-container">
  <div class="alert-panel">
    <ion-icon class="close" style="float:right;cursor:pointer" color="primary" name="close" (click)="dismiss()"></ion-icon>
    <div class="image-container" #svg_image>
      <div class="image" [style.background]="urgent ? '#f53d3d' : 'dodgerblue'" [innerHtml]="image | keepHtml">
          <!-- SVG loads here -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-8 push-2><h3 class="title no-margin">{{ title }}</h3></ion-col> 
        <ion-col col-8 push-2> <p class="subtitle subtle no-margin">{{ subtitle }}</p></ion-col> 
      </ion-row> 
    </ion-grid> 

    <div padding *ngIf="type == 'confirm'">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col><button (click)="dismiss('no')" ion-button full round color="danger">No</button></ion-col>
          <ion-col><button (click)="dismiss('yes')" ion-button full round color="primary">Yes</button></ion-col>
        </ion-row> 
      </ion-grid> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to add the class names 'animated' and 'tada' but it simply won't work.

```
@ViewChild('svg_image') svg;

// Correctly logs the svg element
console.log(this.svg.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1])
setTimeout(() => {
  this.svg.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].classList += ' animated'
  this.svg.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].classList += ` tada`
}, 1000)
```

I couldn't place the `#svg_image` tag on the actual target because it is not defined on render and would throw an error.  So I went with the `childNodes` route.

**What is wrong with the code?**

Comment: Please use `this.svg.nativeElement.querySelector(...)` instead of all those references to `childNodes[]`  If one node were added before any of those child nodes, then your array index would be off, and your code would break.

Answer (score 1):

to add a class to `classList` you need to call `classList.add('tada', 'animated')`

see [the doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: This should work, but I think  it's failing for the same reason mine does which is still a mystery.  It might be worth noting that the `#svg_image` tag does not appear on the element when I inspect it

Answer (score 0):

With the `Renderer` service from `@angular/core` injected, you can add both classes to the element:

```
...
const svgElement = this.svg.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1];
this.renderer.setElementClass(svgElement, "animated tada", true);
...
```

Comment: This should work, but I think it's failing for the same reason mine does which is still a mystery. It might be worth noting that the `#svg_image` tag does not appear on the element when I inspect it.  I think I need a different way of adding the svg since that childNode is not present on page render

Comment: On which lifecycle hook are you running this change?

Comment: I ended up just adding the calsses directly to the svg prior to load